# BroadcastHub doesn't wait for first materialization of Source

Tags: akka-stream

This is what *Akka Streams* documentation states about `Source` materialized from `BroadcastHub` `Sink` ([link](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html)):

> The resulting Source can be materialized any number of times, each materialization effectively attaching a new subscriber. If there are no subscribers attached to this hub then it will not drop any elements but instead backpressure the upstream producer until subscribers arrive.

Therefore I would expect that this:

```java
 Source<String, NotUsed> bcast =
            Source.from(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"))
                  .log("before broadcasting")
                  .runWith(BroadcastHub.of(String.class), materializer);

 bcast.log("after broadcasting")
      .runWith(Sink.ignore(), materializer);
```

would effectively backpressure the upstream of the `BroadcastHub` `Sink` until the `bcast` `Source` is materialized at least once, but it is not the case. If I run the above, the output is:

```
[before broadcasting] Element: 1
[before broadcasting] Element: 2
[before broadcasting] Element: 3
[before broadcasting] Upstream finished.
[after broadcasting] Upstream finished.
```

which is contrary to the documentation, as the elements are effectively dropped and never broadcasted. If I limit the buffer of the `Broadcast` `Sink` like this:

```
        Source<String, NotUsed> bcast =
            Source.from(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"))
                  .log("before broadcasting")
                  .runWith(BroadcastHub.of(String.class, 2), materializer); //buffer smaller than number of events
```

then all the elements are broadcasted:

```
[before broadcasting] Element: 1
[before broadcasting] Element: 2
[after broadcasting] Element: 1
[after broadcasting] Element: 2
[before broadcasting] Element: 3
[before broadcasting] Upstream finished.
[after broadcasting] Element: 3
[after broadcasting] Upstream finished.
```

The way I see it it's either a bug or the documentation is misleading?

Comment: That's my observation as well.  I would call it a bug - if the Source has fewer elements than the `bufferSize` specified in `BroadcastHub.sink`, the runnable graph would "silently" consume the elements when materialized before the consumers have a chance to consume them. Here's a relevant [`blog post`](https://blog.genuine.com/2019/08/akka-dynamic-pub-sub-service/) (in Scala).

Comment: I've opened an issue https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/28327, but it hasn't had much interest :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Akka Expert, however, I did some more tests in Scala. (and also changed from strings to integers)

By throttling the stream to make sure the second stream connects before the hubs upstream source has completed, it works as one would expect.

If the delay of 100 millis is changed to 10 millis then the second response (below) is observed.

I havent checked the source but ...

It looks like the elements do get buffered by the broadcast hub, but if the upstream source has completed when the second sink connects, it sees that the upstream finished, and completes, without receiving the buffered elements.

I'm not sure if that's a documentation issue or a bug.

```
  val sink=BroadcastHub.sink[Int]// (2)

  //10 millis  
  val bcast = Source(1 to (3)).throttle(2,100.millis).
    log("before broadcasting").
    runWith(sink)

  //Thread.sleep(1000) doesnt make any difference
  bcast.log("after broadcasting").runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

100 ms throttle Result

```
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:48:50.168] [broadcastHubTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.stream.Log(akka://broadcastHubTest/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [before broadcasting] Element: 1
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:48:50.168] [broadcastHubTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.stream.Log(akka://broadcastHubTest/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [before broadcasting] Element: 2
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:48:50.172] [broadcastHubTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.stream.Log(akka://broadcastHubTest/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [after broadcasting] Element: 1
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:48:50.172] [broadcastHubTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.stream.Log(akka://broadcastHubTest/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [after broadcasting] Element: 2
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:48:50.233] [broadcastHubTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.stream.Log(akka://broadcastHubTest/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [before broadcasting] Element: 3
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:48:50.233] [broadcastHubTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.stream.Log(akka://broadcastHubTest/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [before broadcasting] Upstream finished.
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:48:50.233] [broadcastHubTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.stream.Log(akka://broadcastHubTest/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [after broadcasting] Element: 3
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:48:50.234] [broadcastHubTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.stream.Log(akka://broadcastHubTest/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [after broadcasting] Upstream finished.
```

10 ms throttle result

```
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:56:26.030] [main] [EventStream(akka://broadcastHubTest)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:56:26.031] [main] [EventStream(akka://broadcastHubTest)] Default Loggers started
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:56:26.136] [broadcastHubTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.stream.Log(akka://broadcastHubTest/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [before broadcasting] Element: 1
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:56:26.137] [broadcastHubTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.stream.Log(akka://broadcastHubTest/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [before broadcasting] Element: 2
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:56:26.137] [broadcastHubTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.stream.Log(akka://broadcastHubTest/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [before broadcasting] Element: 3
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:56:26.137] [broadcastHubTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.stream.Log(akka://broadcastHubTest/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [before broadcasting] Upstream finished.
[DEBUG] [01/29/2020 10:56:26.139] [broadcastHubTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka.stream.Log(akka://broadcastHubTest/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [after broadcasting] Upstream finished.
```